# Why is cloud save recommended for instant games?

Tags: android-instant-apps

On the [Instant Play Games](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/instant-play-games) site google recommends the following:

> Integrate sign-in using Google Play Games Services and a cloud save
>   solution to preserve progress in the game.

However in this other document the following is stated:

> If the player is using a device that runs Android 8.0 (API level 26)
>   or higher, and if your game specifies a targetSandboxVersion of 2,
>   then the player's progress is transferred automatically to the full
>   version of your game. Otherwise, you must transfer the data related to
>   player progress manually. To do so, use one of the following APIs...

So it seems that cloud saves are not needed, there exists a simple API for transferring progress to the main app. So why is cloud save recommended? Am I missing some aspect or restriction of instant apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found at least one reason for this, which seems critical enough:
The instant app data does not persist over for example restarting the device. More info [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/game-instant-app?hl=de#remove-cache-app-data).